# httpclient leak found after a day work

Tags: java, android, memory-leaks, urlconnection

In firts time if work with this source code in my app ,there is no problem ,but if I switch off wifi and try to get some resource from web service my app throws exception with state : Leak Found ,i use the close method of httpclient ,but nothing changes,after day ot two work with this code throws exception.

Stack print:

```
10-17 16:42:00.524: ERROR/AndroidHttpClient(931): Leak found
10-17 16:42:00.524: ERROR/AndroidHttpClient(931): java.lang.IllegalStateException: AndroidHttpClient created and never closed
```

Code :

```
public String getRequest(String url, ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs){
    String resp = "";

        HttpParams httpParameters = new BasicHttpParams();
        HttpProtocolParams.setContentCharset(httpParameters, HTTP.UTF_8);
        HttpProtocolParams.setHttpElementCharset(httpParameters, HTTP.UTF_8);

        AndroidHttpClient httpclient = null;

        try {

            httpclient  = AndroidHttpClient.newInstance("V");

            httpclient.getParams().setParameter("http.protocol.content-charset", HTTP.UTF_8);


            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);

            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs,HTTP.UTF_8));  

            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            InputStream instream = entity.getContent();

            Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(instream, HTTP.UTF_8);

            StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder("");

            char[] tmp = new char[1024];
            int l;
            while ((l = reader.read(tmp)) != -1) {
                buffer.append(tmp, 0, l);
            }

            reader.close();

            resp = buffer.toString().replace("&quot;", "\"");

            Log.d("V", "RESPONSE:-----\n" + resp + "\n--------------");


        } catch (IOException e){

            Log.e("V IOException [Send Request]","IO Exception");
            if((e != null) && (e.getMessage() != null)){
                Log.e("V",e.getMessage().toString());
            }

        } catch (Exception e) { 

            Log.e("V Exception [Send Request]","Exception Requester");
            if((e != null) && (e.getMessage() != null)){
                Log.e("V",e.getMessage().toString());
            }

        }finally {
            if (httpclient != null && httpclient.getConnectionManager() != null) {
                httpclient.close();
                httpclient = null;
            }
        }

        return resp;

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try: httppost.abort(); at the end. Also, I dont think create a httpclient for each request is a good idea, I think is better create the http client as instance variable and reuse for each request.

Comment: If use only one httpclient ,connection freezes,after one minute ,query timeout.This happens after around two hours of running of the application.I i change the connections -> wifi-3G also happens the same

Comment: If i understand well, you have one method "getRequest" so all your request call this method. Every time you call "getRequest" you are creating a new httpclient, also have you tryed what i say? add           `if (httppost != null) { httppost.abort(); }`

Answer (score 0):

I might recommend using EntityUtils class to do what you are doing rather than what you are trying to do though. It will take care most of the problems